# Transmission lines: Why does a real permittivity mean you have a lossless line?

Tags: electromagnetism

My prof said that if you have a relative permittivity which is real, the reflection coefficient is 0 (which means a lossless line). Why is this?

Comment: Was this in reference to some particular arrangement of the transmission line or lines?

Comment: The problem was as follows: A microwave network analyser generates a sinusoidal signal with a frequency of 1GHz with a power of 10mW when a load of 50ohm is placed on the exit of the network. The internal impedance of the network is 50ohm. We attach the load to a coaxial cable with a characteristic impedance of 50ohm, a length of 0.5m and a relative permittivity of 2.25. 

Question: Derive that the transmission line is lossless.
Answer: The permittivity is real which means the line is lossless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you clarified,

> The problem was as follows: A microwave network analyser generates a sinusoidal signal with a frequency of 1GHz with a power of 10mW when a load of 50ohm is placed on the exit of the network. The internal impedance of the network is 50ohm. We attach the load to a coaxial cable with a characteristic impedance of 50ohm, a length of 0.5m and a relative permittivity of 2.25. Question: Derive that the transmission line is lossless. Answer: The permittivity is real which means the line is lossless.

The reflection coefficient being zero wasn't a step in the derivation. The logic is just "a purely real permittivity means the line is lossless". All the other information you were given in the problem statement was a red herring.

If you need an intermediate step, refer to the formula for dielectric loss in the transmission line

$$\alpha = \tan\delta\ \frac{\omega C'Z_0}{2}$$

([source](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/transmission-line-loss))

where $\alpha$ is the attenuation in Np/m, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $C'$ is the line capacitance per unit length, and $Z_0$ is the line characteristic impedance. The loss tangent, $\tan\delta$, is a commonly used metric for dielectric material loss. It is given by

$$\tan\delta = \frac{\epsilon''}{\epsilon'}$$

where $\epsilon'$ is the real part and $\epsilon''$ is the imaginary part of the dielectric permittivity ($\epsilon = \epsilon' + i\epsilon''$).

And from this definition we see that if the permittivity is purely real, its imaginary part is zero, and that leads to zero attenuation.